# Angular CLI no sourcemaps for LESS / SASS

Tags: css, angular, sass, less, angular-cli

Running `ng serve` the CSS is placed into `<style>` tags as expected.

Running `ng serve -ec` the CSS is kept in it's bundle `styles.bundle.css`

Running `ng serve -ec -sm` the CSS is still shown just in the bundle and no sourcemaps seem to be created.

*Note: We're using LESS.*

```
Angular CLI: 1.6.2
Node: 6.11.2
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 5.1.2
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

@angular/cli: 1.6.2
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.0.36
@angular-devkit/core: 0.0.22
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.0.42
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.9.2
@schematics/angular: 0.1.11
@schematics/schematics: 0.0.11
typescript: 2.4.2
webpack: 3.10.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to an issue with Angular CLI has been broken on and off since v1.3.2 and currently is still broken as of v1.7.x

> Did a little more digging & comparing the webpack config file, found that the new CLI is using Webpack plugin "raw-loader" which does not yet support sourcemap (somehow the ticket has been closed but I am not sure if the sourcemap has been implemented).

Only option is to downgrade to v1.6.6 then apply a patch provided by @CharltonC

> In "node_modules@angular\cli\models\webpack-configs\common.js" file, in line 162, Add a line devtool: 'source-map', in the returned common configuration object in the getCommonConfig function, e.g.

```
...
catch (e) { }
return {
    devtool: 'source-map',        // add this line
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
         ...
```

> Tested with the following Commands in terminal (also works with Sass @import):

```
ng serve           // no sourcemap
ng serve -sm -ec   // has sourcemap
ng serve --sourcemap --extract-css  // has sourcemap   
ng serve --sourcemap --extractCss   // has sourcemap
```

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9099